# Pandas drop columns based on column name AND content

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,np.nan,np.nan,5],[3,4,np.nan,np.nan,6]],columns=['a','b','c','Unnamed: 4','Unnamed: 5'])

df
Out[16]: 
   a  b   c  Unnamed: 4  Unnamed: 5
0  1  2 NaN         NaN           5
1  3  4 NaN         NaN           6
```

I want to drop columns that are BOTH all nan AND have 'Unnamed: ' in the name (as often happens when importing a dataframe from a file with columns that have no name in the header). Desired output:

```
   a  b   c  Unnamed: 5
0  1  2 NaN           5
1  3  4 NaN           6
```

I can do:

```
df[[col for col in df.columns if 'Unnamed: ' not in col]]
Out[18]: 
   a  b   c
0  1  2 NaN
1  3  4 NaN
```

or:

```
df.dropna(how='all',axis=1)

Out[19]: 
   a  b  Unnamed: 5
0  1  2           5
1  3  4           6
```

Is there a pythonic way to do both these things simultaneously (connected by AND not OR)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) + [`isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html) + [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

First filter your dataframe for column labels, then calculate which are all null:

```
nulls = df.filter(like='Unnamed').isnull().all()

df = df.drop(nulls[nulls].index, axis='columns')

print(df)

   a  b   c  Unnamed: 5
0  1  2 NaN           5
1  3  4 NaN           6
```